# W3C Grayscale SVG Filters

Tags: html, css, svg, svg-filters

I'm trying to alter the W3C greyscale filter found here: http://www.w3.org/TR/filter-effects-1/#grayscaleEquivalent

This is ridiculously simple on webkit, but I'm only even using this because Gecko only supports calling the filters through  `filters:url(filter.svg`) in the CSS. I don't have much experience with SVG, and the few times I have messed with them they had pretty clear values in percentages, but it's a little more complex with the grayscale one.

So here's the code in the SVG file.

```
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <filter id="grayscale">
  <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0"/>
</svg>
```

Specifically I'm looking to greyscale it to `90%`, so that only `10%` of the color is visible, but I have no idea how this filter works. I found this document here http://www.w3.org/TR/filter-effects-1/#grayscaleEquivalent which is supposed to make sense

Answer (score 14, accepted):

An easier way to do this is to just use the saturation type for feColorMatrix (although the math to do what you want with a matrix isn't hard - if you can do arithmetic you should be able to follow that spec.)

```xml
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <filter id="grayscale">
    <feColorMatrix type="saturate" values="0.10"/>
  </filter>
</svg>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try `<feColorMatrix
      type="luminanceToAlpha" />`
 as an attribute. This will give you something similar to grey scale

Comment: This sets brightness to transparency - the result is typically monochromatic, but hardly the same result as grayscale.